# How to output to the currently visible terminal

Tags: c++, c, linux, tty

I want to output some text as response to the signal `SIGUSR1`

I.e. a user sends `kill -USR1 <pid>` to a process started in background or in another terminal.

I would like to get some output in the terminal where `kill` was invoked.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: http://serverfault.com/a/94995 may be a good place to start. Then you could look at `/proc/<pid>/fd/1` to see where it is sending its console output.

Comment: That's **indeed** a good starting point :)

Comment: Actually you do not know which terminal the signal came from: it could have been issued from a different shell.  If there is only one terminal/window to consider, you can write to /dev/tty

Comment: @HeikoSchäfer I don't have time to try anything out and it doesn't look like anyone knows an obvious answer, so if you do make anything useful from that link (or anything else), please don't hesitate to post an answer to your own question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The comment of @BoBTFish is working. A possible pseudo C++ implementation:

```
// somewhere in code:
std::memset(&sa, 0, sizeof(struct sigaction));
sa.sa_sigaction = sh_dump;
sa.sa_flags = static_cast<int>(SA_SIGINFO); // <- important, else you'll get an invalid siginfo_t pointer
sigaction(SIGUSR1, &sa, NULL);

void sh_dump(int, siginfo_t *info, void *) {

    if(info) {

        // do some locking of your choice

        char *p = NULL;
        char sp[PATH_MAX] = "";

        std::snprintf(sp, PATH_MAX, "/proc/%d/stat", info->si_pid);

        int tty_nr = 0;
        FILE *spf;

        if((spf = std::fopen(sp, "r"))) {

            int iDummy;
            char cDummy, *sDummy;

            // proc(5)
            if(std::fscanf(spf, "%d %ms %c %d %d %d %d", &iDummy, &sDummy, &cDummy, &iDummy, &iDummy, &iDummy, &tty_nr)) {}

            free(sDummy);
            std::fclose(spf);
        }

        // see http://goo.gl/L0pGK1 for an implementation
        if(!(p = ttynameCheckDir(static_cast<dev_t>(tty_nr), "/dev/pts"))) {
            p = ttynameCheckDir(static_cast<dev_t>(tty_nr), "/dev");
        }

        std::ofstream out(p ? p : "/dev/null");

        free(p);

        if(out.is_open()) out << "HELLO" << std::endl;

        // do some unlocking of your choice
    }
}
```

prints `HELLO` on the terminal invoking `kill -USR1 <pid>`

**EDIT:** Using `/proc/#/stat` (Linux only)

Comment: /proc/fd/1 is the same as stdout, it can be redirected.  Not the answer to the question.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure but your code appears to be invalid as your signal handler makes multiple calls to non-reentrant functions.

Answer (score 0):

To ensure you write to the controlling terminal there's a device `/dev/tty` just for this.  It won't work if you are in a detached (no controlling terminal) process.  Just **open(2)** it and **write(2)**  Normally, stdin/stdout/stderr can be redirected, so to assure you are writing somewhere the user will see, open `/dev/tty` and write to it.  `/dev/tty` predates from the ancient times of unix.  It has been conserved for compatibility.  It can be used also to get passwords and ensure you are not redirecting some file descriptor fed to the process.

Comment: As far as I can remember I tried `/dev/tty`, but I want to get the output to the signal emitters terminal.

Comment: What do you mean with the *signal emitters terminal*?

Comment: The terminal where - i.e. `kill -USR1 <pid>` - was invoked

Comment: You cannot know the process who sends the signal.  For the same reason, you cannot know the terminal it(the process that sends the signal) is running on.  The control terminal is the one used to select the processes that receive signals from the kernel (for example, the SIGKILL or SIGINT from the tty device driver, or the SIGHUP on session ending)  You have no general/portable means in UN*X to know other terminal than your control terminal (the one associated to the foreground session)

Comment: The only way to know in the process that sends the signal what happened to the process targeted is to get the result code from the **kill(2)** system call (if it returns 0, the signal was sent to at least one process)  This is the only way to print on the terminal of the signal issuer process.

Comment: I **can** get the process which emitted the signal. See the very first comment of @BoBTFish. My answer shows a working example.

Comment: @HeikoSchäfer, even if you **can** get the process id of the process which emitted the signal, probably you won't get reliable acces to `/proc/<pid>` of that process if it belongs to another user.  I have not seen any information about the process control terminal there, so you cannot write there (to `/proc/<pid>/fd/1`) in case you have redirected input to the **kill(1)** command (or to the program that sends the signal)  At most you can do a best effort thing, but no more than that.  You can get killed by the kernel as a means of finishing your session (SIGHUP) or accesing bad mem (SIGSEGV)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71859/discussion-between-luis-colorado-and-heiko-schafer).

Comment: Sorry, no need to discuss in chat. I got it exactly how I need my problem solved.